LARAVEL: how to create id for all logs and record in the container
hi I was wondering if it was possible for me to generate id for all logs in the laravel project and record ids in the container, I previously tried to create a middleware file :
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $requestId = (string) Str::uuid();
 
        Log::shareContext([
            'request-id' => $requestId
        ]);

and register this middle file in the kernel.php file, I wanna ask if there is any other methods to not generate id in every log, can I generate log ids in a global method? MANY THANKS!
I tried to make it in generating id in every log.

Here is the way you can do it.
Create a Middleware instead of trying to modify every log statement, you can create a middleware that generates a unique identifier and attaches it to the log context. This middleware will be executed for every incoming request, ensuring that each log within that request shares the same identifier.enter code here
Register the Middleware you can register this middleware globally so that it applies to all incoming requests.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LogRequestId
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $requestId = (string) Str::uuid();

        // Share the request ID with the log context
        Log::setDefaultDriver('request'); // Use the appropriate log channel if needed
        Log::info('New request', ['request-id' => $requestId]);

        // Attach the request ID to the request for future use if needed
        $request->requestId = $requestId;

        return $next($request);
    }
}

